# How to go to last 5 commit of a particular file?

Tags: git, github

All,
I have a file front.js in my project. Now this file(front.js) last commit was 2bafd98be9a combined with other file. Here is now how can i get code of this file(front.js) last 5 commit ie., 9002040c2bf3 of this file from last commit.

Comment: *Last 5 commits which contain a particular file?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to:

```
$ git checkout 2bafd98be9a~5 -- front.js
```

This will try to get the file 5 commits before `2bafd98be9a`